# How to do automatic functional test for Facebook Like button in local web server?

Tags: facebook

Our project is a Web application. We want to add Facebook Like button on our web pages. To test the functionality of Facebook Like works, we want to write some cucumber automatice functional tests.

The problem is, if a user (either real user or automatic test) click the Facebook Like button, the web page will send a message to Facebook server. And then Facebook server will callback to this web page to get some information (title/image/url/type etc, which are write in web page header meta tags). But our tests are running in **local server**, consequently the Facebook can not access. So there be something wrong.

So I'm wandering is there a solution to solve this problem. (Maybe not only for Facebook, but also any situation we want conversation between other systems and our local server)

Answer (score 2):

In order for a Like Button to work, it **has** to be able to connect to the Facebook servers. There's no workaround, short of capturing the request and returning information, but I'm not even confident that would work. Can you not do the testing on a development server that can be accessed from the web?

You could .htaccess it so that only your team and the Facebook servers could connect to it.